# SSH доступ по ключу

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

Система Ubuntu 11.10, подключаюсь к серверу на FreeBSD 8.0.

На своей машине выполнил `ssh-keygen | ssh-copy-id username@hostname`

При попытке подключения `ssh username@hostname` запрашивает пароль. Лог:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.10 [10.10.10.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/usernam/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2p1 FreeBSD-20090522 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee
debug1: Host '10.10.10.10' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Пробовал так же вручную копировать. Права стоят 700/600.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Испытывал ровно такую же проблему: `ssh-copy-id`, на удалённом хосте права на `~/.ssh` и `~/.ssh/*` стоят правильные, но ключ не принимается. Проблема оказалась в правах на домашнюю папку пользователя на удалённой машине, в которой находится `~/.ssh` (собственно в `~`).

Смущает `ssh-keygen | ssh-copy-id username@hostname` - зачем здесь пайп? `ssh-keygen` создаёт ключ и кладёт его в `~/.ssh`, а `ssh-copy-id` берёт ключ из `~/.ssh` и складывает его на `username@hostname`. Между командами ничего не передаётся, пайп не нужен.

Правильным вариантом кажется всё-таки `ssh-keygen && ssh-copy-id username@hostname`.

Так что автору надо проверить 2 вещи - положилась ли вообще публичная часть сгенерированного ключа на удалённый сервер и правильные permissions на весь путь до `~/.ssh` на удалённом сервере (включая `~` и всё, что выше).

Answer (score 1):

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ''`
2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh Я@server_доступа_по_ключу "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2"`
3. Первый раз запросит пароль. Затем, - по ключу.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим ответом, кроме authorized_keys2, почему не просто authorized_keys?По крайней мере в man указано именно такое имя.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/116177/whats-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-authorized-keys2

Comment: а где пароль взять , я его ищу а его всё нет и нет :(